# Find the students with avg > 5 for every class they attend

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
student_id, class, grade
```

Each student can attend between 6 and 10 classes, and can get any number of grades at each class attended.

So, for example, the student with student_id = 1 can attend 6 classes and he/she can have 2 grades at physics, 6 grades at mathematics, 4 grades at english and so on, and the student with student_id = 2 can attend 10 classes he/she can have 7 grades at physics, 2 grades at mathematics, 7 grades at english, 3 grades at geography and so on.

I need to find only the students (well, student_id's) who got the avg(grade) at list 5 AT EVERY CLASS HE/SHE ATTENDED.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply group the data twice:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM (
    SELECT student_id, class, AVG(grade) AS avg_grade
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY student_id, class
) AS x
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(class) = COUNT(CASE WHEN avg_grade >= 5 THEN 1 END)
```